# How to retrieve a single row from foreach in JSP(Spring framework)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsp

I want to know, How to retrieve a single row from foreach in JSP.
My database table has two rows and I want to get a maximum Id row from that.

I'm using this part in my Query for retrieval of a row

```
FROM categories ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

By using query part mentioned above it works fine and retrieves a row with maximum Id in my JSP code. But after fetching the maximum row, other rows are displayed  like this:

> item2cat1 item2catdec1
>       cat1  catdec1

I want to retrieve 1st row only i.e. **item2cat1    item2catdec1**.

**My JSP code is**

```
<c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="names">
        <tr>
            <td>${names.category1}</td>
            <td>${names.desccategory1}</td>
            <td>

        </tr>
    </c:forEach>

**My controller is** 
@RequestMapping("/")
    //mapping URL for retrieve data from the database
    public String setupForm(Map<String, Object> map) {
        Categories allcategories = new Categories();
        //create a new abject (must be a previous assign Dao name)
        map.put("names", allcategories);
        //view page's command name 
        map.put("itemList", allcategoryService.getAllCategories());
        //view page's List name 
        return "studentview";
        //view page name
    }

**my select Query is in daoimpl is**
@Override
    public List getAllCategories() {
        return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Categories ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1").list();
//SQL data retrieve query... model must input for the query
    }
```

I'm newer for spring, If someone can get this single row without using foreach from other method please update me.